# Is it possible to install only components of Material that we use?

Tags: ios, components, cocoapods, podfile

In my iOS project, in a Podfile, I have something like this:

```
pod 'Material', '~> 2.16'
```

But for now, I use only TextField component.

Is there a way to instal it only, with all its features ?

Comment: According to this: https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/blob/master/Material.podspec no, you can't. You can create your own local podspec to get only the files you want, but you might encounter issues on updates (used of another file, etc.)

Comment: Note that's a long work, because if needs `IconButton.swift` (there is a reference to `IconButton`), which itself might need other files, etc. To do it, I create a Test.podspec, copy/paste the current podspec, but modified name to "MaterialTextField " and the `source_files` to have only the `TextField.swift` file, then a `pod spec lint` on it, and read the error, etc: "error: use of undeclared type IconButton", etc. Afterwards to use it in your code, you might do `pod 'MaterialTextField', :podspec => 'Test.podspec'`

Comment: I see, thank you. @Larme If you like you can make an answer, so I will accept it.

Comment: I added a link to another one MaterialComponents, that have a subspec TextField. I don't know theses pods, I don't know if they behave the same way and have the same functionalities, same UI, but could be worth a look, and quicker way that I just though of to fix the "inter dependencies".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Material.podspec](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/blob/master/Material.podspec), there is only one big pod, not subspec.

You could create your own iteration.

Create a `MaterialTextField.podspec` file with (it's the content of the `Material.podspec` with small modification annoted with ***). You could git rid of the subspec, and use only a "spec" since there is no other subspec, but I didn't want to change the file too much.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = 'MaterialTextField' ***
    s.version = '2.16.4'
    s.swift_version = '4.0'
    s.license = 'BSD-3-Clause'
    s.summary = 'A UI/UX framework for creating beautiful applications.'
    s.homepage = 'http://cosmicmind.com'
    s.social_media_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/cosmicmindcom'
    s.authors = { 'CosmicMind, Inc.' => 'support@cosmicmind.com' }
    s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material.git', :tag => s.version }

    s.default_subspec = 'Core'
    s.platform = :ios, '8.0'

    s.subspec 'Core' do |s|
        s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
        s.ios.source_files = 'Sources/**/iOS/TextField.swift' ***
        s.requires_arc = true
        s.resource_bundles = {
            'com.cosmicmind.material.icons' => ['Sources/**/*.xcassets'],
            'com.cosmicmind.material.fonts' => ['Sources/**/*.ttf']
        }
    s.framework = 'UIKit' ***
        # s.dependency 'Motion', '~> 1.4.3' ***
    end
end
```

I just modified the lines with ***.
I'm not sure that you need the s.framework for UIKit though, and don't know if you can bypass the dependency of `Motion`.
You might also want to remove the fonts/xcassets.

Then, you can do

```
$> pod spec lint --verbose
```

You should get errors like that:

```
> ERROR | [MaterialTextField/Core] xcodebuild:  MaterialTextField/Sources/iOS/TextField.swift:295:46: error: use of undeclared type 'IconButton'
```

So there is the `IconButton` object that it doesn't know (it depends on it), so you have modify the podpsec:

```
s.ios.source_files = 'Sources/**/iOS/TextField.swift', 'Sources/**/iOS/IconButton.swift'
```

To add it.

But it might need other imports too, so you'll need to run a lot of `pod spec lint` until the end, and so on, and might need to fix other kind of errors.

You might at the end have the whole pod because there are plenty of "inter dependency".

In Objective-C, looking for `@class` and `#import "File.h"` might have been easier than in Swift where the imports are "implicit".

Also, you might keep on that version and might have to redo all it again in next update of their pod.

Finally, if by patience and miracle you get what you want, you can add it in your podfile using:

```
pod 'MaterialTextField', :podspec => 'Relative/Path/To/MaterialTextField.podspec'
```

I'm not sure about that one (or `:path` instead of `:podspec`), but if I recall correctly that should do it.

**Be careful, you might break the licence use.**

You also might ask the author (open a ticket ?) to break their pod into multiple pods like this [MaterialComponents.podspec](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/MaterialComponents.podspec) (that I just saw a few minutes ago answering another question).

**EDIT:**
Another way do avoid too much `pod spec lint` to to clone the repo, create a project, add the `TextField.swift`, check if it compiles, add the missing files, check if it compiles, etc. It might be much faster.